# In line Conditional Expression or Function - Pythonic?

Tags: coding-style, python, ternary-operator, conditional-expressions

I have a situation where I would like to conditionally slice a string from the
reported position of an '@' symbol; the condition being: slice the string if
the '@' is there, else leave it untouched. I thought up two ways, one using a 
function, the other using an inline conditional expression. Which method is the
most Pythonic?

Using a function

```
>>> def slice_from_at(inp):
...     res = inp.find('@')
...     if res == -1:
...         return None
...     else:
...         return res     
>>> c = 'agent_address@agent_address'
>>> c[:slice_from_at(c)]
... 'agent_address'
```

Using an inline conditional expression

```
>>> c = 'agent_address@agent_address'
>>> c[:None if c.find('@') == -1 else c.find('@')]
... 'agent_address'
```

Although using the inline conditional expression is more terse and, some may 
argue more economical - is the function method is more Pythonic because it more 
readable?

Comment: I suspect that `c.partition('@')` or `c.split('@')` is even more readable, but I'm not sure if that really addresses your question?

Comment: Indeed, it is really a question about style rather than a solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: TIL `None` can be used in slices in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is a function more readable, it is also reusable.

The inline expression may call `c.find('@')` twice, which is inefficient.

As Useless has mentioned in the comments, there are already built in functions to do this; you really don't need to define your own function in this case:

```
agent,_,address = c.partition('@')
```

---

By the way, a callback is a function that is passed in as an argument and called later. You don't have a callback since it is not being called later. I think it should just be called a function.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to remove the callback reference

Answer (score 3):

Most Pythonic?

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

```
def slice_from_at(inp):
    if '@' in inp:
        return inp.partition('@')[2]
    return inp
```

If you're more concerned about speed than readability, try [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
def slice_from_at(inp):
    return inp.rsplit('@', 1)[-1]
```

Neither of your examples includes a "callback". Nor should they.

A well-named function that does one thing and does that one thing well is about as Pythonic as it gets. If it's backed-up with unit tests, so much the better.

Comment: Thanks, although I accepted @unutbu's answer because it was a question about style, the use of str.partition is really neat!

Comment: My first instinct was to use `str.partition()`, but I think `str.rsplit()` is probably better since it does the same thing for you but without the initial search for the `@`.

Comment: That conditional logic for `partition` isn't needed at all, because there is also `rpartition`. `inp.rpartition('@')[2]` works fine.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I'm kicking myself that I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead?

```
c.split('@')[0]
```

Comment: Because this returns the data *before* the '@'.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Isn't that what the OP wanted?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: The examples in the question *also* show the data before the '@', and the code extracts the prefix.

Comment: The actual way to do this would be `c.split('@')[-1]`

Comment: @Paul: By “this”, did you mean “what the OP wants” or “what Johnsyweb suggests”?

Comment: @Paul: The OP's own sample code fetches the content before the `@`, so I would be surprised if `-1` is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The stylistic reason that [existing, but you could have wrote them yourself] functions like `.partition()` or `.rsplit()` are cleaner than `c[:slice_from_at(c)]` that the API of `slice_from_at()` is low-level: it returns an index into the string that it was given, but that index only makes sense to cut the string, so why not return the desired fragment(s) of the string directly?

Generally, indexes into sequences are considered unpythonic when a higher-level alternative exists, as evidenced by the growing amount of built-in helpers that reduce exposure to indexes.  Particular examples that come to mind:

- `zip()` and `enumerate()` reducing need for `for i in range(len(seq)):` loops.
- `substring in string`, `str.split()`, then `str.partition()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer string methods when they do the job easily, but for completeness, regular expressions should be mentioned:

```
re.sub('^.*@', '', c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I code like this:

```
if '@' in c:
    c = c[:c.find('@')]
```

I don't move 2 lines of code in to separate function in most of cases.

Comment: no sense worrying about which if-statement you should use when it turns out its not needed.  Cutting code out is the most pythonic thing to do,  `c = c[:c.find('@')]` works on its own.